# Xcode int returning random numbers

Tags: xcode, delegates, arraylist, int

I have a class called Places with placeId declared as Int.

```
int placeId;
```

I have a method which return my placeId/

```
- (int)  getPlaceId;

- (int)getPlaceId{
return placeId;
}
```

I created an arrayList to store Places object into that array.
When I run the method to get my placeID, I seem to be getting back a range of weird numbers. Eg. 1234567.

Any idea why this is happening?

```
NSString *tempInt = [tempObject objectForKey:@"placeId"]; 
    NSString *tempString = [tempObject objectForKey:@"name"]; //2

    //convert temptInt to integer
    NSInteger myInt = (NSInteger)tempInt;

    Places *p = [[Places alloc]set:myInt andb:tempString];
    [del.delegateArrayPlaces addObject:p];
```

Here is how I add, what other codes do you need?

Comment: Could you show us the code where you create the array?

Comment: You cast a `NSString *` to an `NSInteger`???  How will that work?

Comment: @trojanfoe Apologies, I just started on XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code your integer ivar get's actually assigned to a pointer and this is what you get.
Show us some code to help you

Edit (after posting code):

```
NSString *tempString = [tempObject objectForKey:@"name"]; //2

//convert temptInt to integer
NSInteger myInt = [tempString intValue];
```